# in python 3.12 i see type ListOrSet[T] = list[T] | set[T], but how do i use this?

Tags: python, types

In the new python 3.12 docs i see this:

```py
type ListOrSet[T] = list[T] | set[T]
```

But I dont know how or where this is used.
Is this for type hinting and where can this be used?

The docs are here:
https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/

But to me it is not clear, perhaps because i never really used the typing module.

Can i use this for Type Hinting ?

Comment: It sounds like you should go through the basics of type hinting first. This is combining about 4 different features that are all pretty simple on their own, but they're all probably new to you. Explaining 4 different features isn't a great fit for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @user2357112,  i use type hinting quite a lot which is why this feature looks interesting. but in the past i have done this `x : list[str]` . . .   so it seems very similar but adding a keyword `type` and replacing the `:` with an `=` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `ListOrSet[T]` notation is used for type hinting in Python.

It allows you to create custom type aliases using the TypeAlias syntax.

It's primarily used to improve type hints, making your code more readable and self-explanatory. Mostly,this creates a custom type alias `ListOrSet`, which can represent either a list or a set containing elements of type T.

let's say You use `ListOrSet` as a type hint for variables, function parameters, and return types, just like you would with any other built-in types.

For instance:

```
def test_typing(data: ListOrSet[int]) -> ListOrSet[int]:
    result = [x * 2 for x in data]
    return result
```

In this example, the `test_typing` function accepts an argument of type `ListOrSet[int]`, which can be either a list or a set of integers, and it returns a value of the same type.

Comment: okay, this makes sense.  so the `T` in the example is replaced with the type that the user wants like `list[str]` which is a list of strings.  I suppose that T is just a generic placeholder for any type...